# Neutered bunny is marking the couch near the cat, help?

Tags: rabbits, marking

Before neutering my bunny was obssessed with mating with the cat, Neutered male, and now he is still keen to be near the cat, but is also peeing on the couch right in front of where the cat sleeps. Bunny has a large litter box in his enclosure which is about 4ft by 8ft.  I just learned about keeping other animals out and keeping the boundary secure. I want him to romp free in bunny safe rooms of the house but don't want to give him more chances to mark.  What can I do? I do get him back in his enclosure as soon as he pees, but he is also hard to pick up :( and I hate stressing him out.

Comment: How recently was your bunny neutered? It can take a few weeks for the neuter to fully have an effect, so it may just take a bit longer. Is your rabbit otherwise litter trained?